# How do I use query parameters in SQL conditional statement

Tags: sql, django

I am trying to execute a SQL command to return data from the database but using query parameters as a condition in the SQL statement. This is the code I am running and I get this error:

```
def get(self, *args):
    followers = self.request.query_params.get('')

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(
            "SELECT authapi_user.id AS profile_id
                    FROM authapi_tweet 
                    INNER JOIN authapi_user 
                    ON authapi_user.id = authapi_tweet.author_id 
                    WHERE authapi_tweet.author_id 
                    IN %s 
                    ORDER BY created_on 
                    DESC;", followers)

        table = cursor.fetchall()
        return Response(table)
```

> return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
>   django.db.utils.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error

This is an example of the URL request:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tweets/alldata/?0=1&1=2

Comment: which paramater are you trying to catch from the request?

Comment: What is your underlying SQL database (e.g. MySQL, Postgres) ?

Comment: @abhyudai I am catching the 1,2.

Comment: @timBiegeleisen This is SQLite

Comment: What does `followers` contain, and how many values do you expect there?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen followers is definited here and it is meant to capture the parameters from the URL. Correct me if I'm doing that wrong... The amount of values will vary in each query, which is why I wanted to create this in a dynamic way.

Comment: The goal here is to send a list of values through a GET request and then use those values as a condition to check for when making the database query

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQLite, then you should be using `?` as the positional placeholder in the prepared statement.  Given that you are trying to bind a tuple, you can generate an `IN` clause with the correct number of placeholders.

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    sql = """
        SELECT au.id AS profile_id
        FROM authapi_tweet at
        INNER JOIN authapi_user au ON au.id = at.author_id 
        WHERE at.author_id IN {}
        ORDER BY created_on DESC"""
    term = ', ?'*(len(followers)-1) if len(followers) > 1 else ''
    in_clause = '(?' + term + ')'
    sql = sql.format(in_clause)
    cursor.execute(sql, followers)
    table = cursor.fetchall()
    return Response(table)
```

Note that the above uses a trick to generate a `WHERE IN` clause looking something like the following:

```
WHERE at.author_id IN (?, ?, ?)    -- assuming followers is a tuple of length 3
```

Then, we pass the `followers` tuple as the second parameter to `cursor.execute()` as you were already doing.